# connecting chars*

Tags: c++, c, char

How would I connect to char* strings to each other.
For example:

```
char* a="Heli";
char* b="copter";
```

How would I connect them to one char c which should be equal to "Helicopter" ?

Comment: Do you want to do this in C or C++?

Comment: It is ill-advised to use a `char*` to point to a string literal:  the contents of a string literal are not modifiable, so it is a good idea to use a `const char*`.  (In C string literals are of type `char[N]` and in C++ they are of type `const char[N]`, but in both languages you can implicitly get a `char*` to the string literal, which is for backwards compatibility with really old code.)

Comment: **[Concatenation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation)** is the term you're looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`strncat`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncat/)

Or use [string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)s.

Comment: As Tony noted, you can't call it as `strncat("Hello ", "world\n", 6)`. You need quite a few extra functions.

Answer (score 6):

```
size_t newlen = strlen(a) + strlen(b);
char *r = malloc(newlen + 1);
strcpy(r, a);
strcat(r, b);
```

Comment: In C++, malloc() returns a void* and you're assigning it to a char*. That produces an error: 'cannot convert from void* to char*'.  Casting like this makes it work:  char *r = (char *)malloc(newlen + 1);

Comment: malloc is C and in C you don't cast `void*` into another type when assigning it. In C++ you use the `new` operator, which returns a properly typed pointer.

Answer (score 3):

In C++:

```
std::string foo(a);
std::string bar(b);
std::string result = foo+bar;
```

Answer (score 3):

If your system has asprintf() (pretty common these days), then it's easy:

```
char* p;
int num_chars = asprintf(&p, "%s%s", a, b);
```

The second argument is a format string akin to `printf()`, so you can mix in constant text, ints, doubles etc., controlling field widths and precision, padding characters, justification etc..  If num_chars != -1 (an error), then `p` then points to heap-allocated memory that can be released with `free()`.  Using `asprintf()` avoids the relatively verbose and error-prone steps to calculate the required buffer size yourself.

In C++:

```
std::string result = std::string(a) + b;
```

Note: `a + b` adds two pointers - not what you want, hence at least one side of the `+` operator needs to see a `std::string`, which will ensure the string-specific concatenation operator is used.

(The accepted answer of `strncat` is worth further comment: it can be used to concatenate more textual data after an ASCIIZ string in an existing, writeable buffer, in-so-much as that buffer has space to spare.  You can't safely/portably concatenate onto a string literal, and it's still a pain to create such a buffer.  If you do it using `malloc()` to ensure it's exactly the right length, then `strcat()` can be used in preference to `strncat()` anyway.)

Comment: I think `asprintf()` returns the number of bytes printed or -1 if an error occurs, not the pointer to allocated memory. There should be an argument before the format string of type `char **`, which is the address of the `char *` variable to which the pointer to allocated memory is assigned (if no error occurs). Unless `asprintf()` has different prototypes for some libraries. Anyway, nice and thorough answer. +1

Comment: @William: wow - I'd forgotten that... been in the C++ world too long!  Will update... thanks.